# change color menu in design time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, winforms

There is any form to change the menu color when the mouse is over it in designing  time in visual studio 2008?
Or at least change all the menu items at the same time in execution time
I'm using windows forms

Comment: I assume you mean menu of your application (not VS menus) when you have your form open in design mode. Unless you create your own (custom) menu as a control and use the Component.DesignMode

Comment: It's correct, i'm talking about the menus of my application. And i'm using the standar menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did't found a way to do this in desing time, but with code i need change the RenderMode to custom, by default use the the "manager" option.

> It's not posible set a RenderMode of Custom directly; instead, the ToolStrip sets it when you supply a custom renderer.
>
> Source [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/Tool,_Menu,_and_Status_Strips%E2%80%94Customizing_the_ToolStrip_Rendering)

with this, inherits a class of ToolStripRenderer

```
class CustomRenderer : ToolStripRenderer
{
  //customize here
}
```

and call it when the forms is load

```
private void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    menuStrip1.Renderer = new  CustomRenderer();
}
```